# jQuery data table don't destroy the grid until new response comes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery data tables. I have my own control to search data. what I want is it should not destroy the grid unless new data comes in response.

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: post your relevant code here/create a jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: what I want is previous grid should be there with data unless new response is send from server.

Comment: that i understood buddy, but without the code it difficult fix the issue . if possible create a jsfiddle with all relevant code, i`ll check it

Comment: The API fnReloadData might help you